# How can I install libnginx-mod-http-perl on Ubuntu when NGINX is installed from nginx.org?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apt, package-management

On My Ubuntu 22.04 server, I prefer to install NGINX from the [nginx.org repo](https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#Ubuntu) instead of the official Ubuntu repo.

My `/etc/apt/preferences.d/99nginx` file looks like this:

```
Package: *
Pin: origin nginx.org
Pin: release o=nginx
Pin-Priority: 900
```

I already installed NGINX from it. The installed NGINX package is, as expected, form the nginx.org repo:

```
# apt policy nginx
nginx:
  Installed: 1.23.2-1~jammy
  Candidate: 1.23.2-1~jammy
  Version table:
 *** 1.23.2-1~jammy 900
        900 http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu jammy/nginx amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.23.1-1~jammy 900
        900 http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu jammy/nginx amd64 Packages
     1.23.0-1~jammy 900
        900 http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu jammy/nginx amd64 Packages
     1.21.6-1~jammy 900
        900 http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu jammy/nginx amd64 Packages
     1.18.0-6ubuntu14.3 500
        500 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.18.0-6ubuntu14 500
        500 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

The problem is that now I need a NGINX module, *libnginx-mod-http-perl*, but I cannot install it:

```
# apt install libnginx-mod-http-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx : Conflicts: nginx-common but 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.3 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

*libnginx-mod-http-perl* is also part of `nginx-extras` (a package from Ubuntu), but I cannot install it because it requires the official Ubuntu package, not the one provided by nginx.org.

I'm lost here. **Why can't I libnginx-mod-http-perl?** How can I fix it?